# Winexe error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE executing script from Linux to Windows Server 2012

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012, remote-access

I've installed winexe on my linux machine. I want to use it to execute some script on a Windows Servre 2012. It doesn't work, the error is NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE.

I've followed this guide to install winexe: https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Winexe

I've enabled SMBv1 and SMBv2 on Windows Server. The script I'm trying to execute is:

./bin/winexe -U administrator%pwd4administrator //serverip "cmd.exe"
I've done nothing else. Am i missing something?

The workgroup on my linux machine (on /etc/samba/smb.conf.) is "MYGROUP", the workgroup on Windows server is "WORKGROUP". I tryed this way:

./bin/winexe -U administrator%pwd4administrator -W WORKGROUP //serverip "cmd.exe"
But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax is

```
./winexe -U HOME/administrator%password123 //192.168.0.1 "cmd /c netstat"
```

and it works with SMBv2, as long as the executing user has 'remote logon' rights.

You can not execute interactive stuff like cmd.exe by itself.